# Prove that $G$ is cyclic and has exactly two nontrivial subgroups.

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

1- Let $G$ be an abelian group of order $2p$, where $p$ is an odd prime. Prove that $G$ is
cyclic and has exactly two nontrivial subgroups. Write out in full each theorem or
other previously proven result that you use.?

my try is
I assume $G$ has no nontrivial subgroups.
Because $G$ is trivial by the assumption above, then $G$ is cyclic.

If $G$ has exactly one nontrivial subgroups $H$, consider the subgroup generated by a nonidentity element $g$ in $G/H$

what should I do  next

===================

2- how you would go about to …find all homomorphic images of a group.?

I know how to find for specific group like $\Bbb Z_4$ or $\Bbb Z_8$ but here not specific any group

how to start

please help me in the two questions

Comment: Beware of the term "trivial subgroup". Most of the time this means "a subgroup that contains only the identity", but some people also call the group $G$ itself a trivial subgroup in $G$. Looks like the author of the problem does exactly that.

Comment: What are the possible orders of elements of a group of order $2p$? What's the order of a product of two elements of different order?

Comment: To assume that $\;G\;$ has no non-trivial sbgps. is *not* the negation of the given question. You still have to take into account the "exactly two" part...

Comment: Do you know the Sylow theorems? Having exactly two non-trivial subgroups falls out immediately, and you can then quite easily show $G \cong C_p \times C_2 \cong C_{2p}$.
  
As for finding all homomorphic images of a general group $G$, you know that under an arbitrary homomorphism $\phi$, $\textrm{im}\, \phi \cong G/N$ where $N = \textrm{ker}\, \phi$. So it's enough to find all normal subgroups of $G$ and form the quotients by each. This is where something like character theory becomes quite powerful.

Comment: @ah11950, isn't Sylow overkill for abelian groups?

Comment: Yes it very much is... I'd been working on lots of classification problems with Sylow and just kind of went into 'autopilot'!

Answer (score 0):

By Cauchy, $G$ has an element of order $2$, say $x$, and an element of order $p$, say $y$. Since $G$ is Abelian, the order of $z:=xy$ is $o(z)=\operatorname{lcm}(2,p)^\dagger=\frac{2p}{\gcd(2,p)}$ ; but $\gcd(2,p)=1$, because $p$ is an *odd* prime; so,  $o(z)=2p$ and hence $G$ is cyclic.

As for second part of the first point, let $H$ be a nontrivial subgroup of $G$ distinct from $\langle x\rangle$ and $\langle y \rangle$. By Lagrange, $|H|=p$ or $|H|=2$; in the former case, $\langle 
y \rangle H$ has size $p^2$, which is bigger than $2p$ for $p$ odd prime: contradiction; in the latter case, $\langle x\rangle H$ is a subgroup of $G$ of order $4$: contradiction, because $4\nmid 2p$ for $p$ odd prime. Therefore, such a $H$ doesn't exist, and $\langle  x\rangle $ and $\langle  y\rangle $ are the only nontrivial subgroups of $G$.

---

$^\dagger$By Lagrange, $\langle x\rangle$ and $\langle y\rangle$ intersect trivially, and hence $(xy)^n\stackrel{G\textit{ Abelian}}{=}x^ny^n=e\iff x^n=e\vee y^n=e$.

Answer (score 0):

An abelian group whose order is the product of distinct primes is cyclic,  because it is the product of its Sylow subgroups,  which are cyclic and of relatively prime order.

And, a cyclic group has a unique subgroup of each order dividing the order of the group.